# Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to make animations in jupyter notebook, but the system needs the package ffmpeg for making mp4 arxives. What happens is that I'm working in a virtual space, and I don't have permission to make `sudo install ffmpeg` instead of this I think the only alternative that I have is `pip install ffmpeg`. But when I make this, the error stills the same.

I also tried to force the location of the ffmpeg package but also doesn't work.

`plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = ".local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ffmpeg"`

If someone have any solution or intuition to solve the problem in this case it will be very helpful.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` Python package is just a thin wrapper around the command line `ffmpeg` utility.  You may be able to build `ffmpeg` yourself without using `apt`.

Comment: With building it, you mean downloading the package from [link](http://ffmpeg.org/) ? And after unzip the package in the directory where we are working with python?

Comment: What I mean is downloading the source and compiling it yourself.  You can try downloading one of the "static builds", which can be unzipped to a location you control, but all of this is fairly advanced.  Why can't you do `sudo apt install`?

Comment: Is a virtual space of an organization. Im only a studient and dont have permision to do this, I can only do pip install. It will be difficult to obtain this permision, if is the only option

Comment: Not at all, as I said.  Have you investigated the ffmpeg web site?  They have a set of "static builds" which are pre-built binaries and libraries you can copy into place.  Otherwise, you'll need to compile it from source.